# The relation of range to $\sin\left(\theta \right)$ vs $\sin\left(2\theta \right)$

Tags: homework-and-exercises, kinematics, projectile

I recently conducted a projectile motion experiment where I fire projectiles from a Nerf gun. I wanted to see the relation the range had with $sin\left(\theta \right)$. I saw that this gave me a parabolic graph and so I saw that the range is proportional to $sin\left(2\theta \right)$.

But when I graphed range vs $sin\left(2\theta \right)$, I got a spiral relation between the two. These were my results:

```
sin(2theta):
            0.34
            0.64
            0.87
            0.98
            0.98
            0.87
            0.64
            0.34
```

As you can see the results just repeat themselves which causes the spiral relation. I was expecting a linear relation, so why is this happening? Or is this what is supposed to happen? I am not quiet sure.

Here is what the graph looks like currently:

[image]

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Assuming that your nerf gun, fires each projectile with same speed, we have only one variable ,viz, $'\theta'$.

For a projectile thrown with velocity $'\nu'$ and angle projection (with horizontal) of $'\theta'$, the range is given by,

$R=\frac{2\nu \sin{\theta } cos\theta}{g} $, $\tag1$

In this relation, R is proportional to both $\sin{\theta}$ and $\cos{\theta}$.

$R=\frac{\nu (2\sin{\theta } cos\theta)}{g} $,

**Transformation (1) :**

Since, $\sin{2\theta}=2 \sin{\theta} \cos{\theta}$, equation $(1)$ can be reformed as,

$R=\frac{\nu \sin{2\theta } }{g} $ , $\tag2$

This equation gives us the relation between the range and $\sin{\theta}$, and from this equation it can be seen that the range of a projectile is proportional to  $\sin{2\theta}$.

Furthermore, $\nu$ and $g$ are constant, therefore we can conclude that, $R \propto \sin{2\theta}$.

**Tranformation (2) :**

Another approach to manipulate  equation $(1)$ is to turn $\cos{\theta}$ into $\sin{\theta}$, and by substituting $\cos{\theta}$ by,

$\cos{\theta}=\sqrt{1-\sin^{2}{\theta}}$,

$R=\frac{2\nu\sin{\theta} \sqrt{1-\sin^{2}{\theta}}}{g} $, $\tag{3}$

This gives us the relation between $R$ and $\sin{\theta}$

Since you are plotting your graph between Range and $sin{\theta}$  $(or \sin{2\theta})$, Let

$y=R$, and $x=sin{\theta}$  $(or \sin{2\theta})$,

**From equation (2)**,

$y=kx$ ,

Here $k=\frac{v}{g}$ and $x=\sin{2\theta}$

**From equation (3)**,

$y=k'x\sqrt{1-x^2}$,

Here, $k'=\frac{2\nu}{g}$ , and $x=\sin{\theta}$.

This should answer your question.

Answer (score 1):

The range for projectiles shot at $\theta$ and $90-\theta$ should be the same as  $sin(2\theta) = sin(2(90-\theta)).$
So, what I guess is the obtuse angles are showing a different trend compared to the acute angles. (You will have to check whether it is true because you have not provided the values of $\theta$ in the graph).

And if that it is true, it can be explained by the drag effect of air. Projectiles shot at obtuse angles have a longer time of flight and suffer greater loss in horizontal velocity due to drag as compared to those shot at acute angles. If the drag effect were negligible you could have got a perfect straight-line for all angles.